# Call Menu design of header.phtml into 1Column.phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, template, design

I am working on front end design changes for my website. My requirement to change position of Top Menu design which is written in header.phtml page and i want to use this line into 1Column.phtml page. How can i call this line,

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

on 1column.phtml. So that i can get output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by XML in your `page.xml` or `local.xml` file of your theme.

```
<default>
  <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
       <label>Navigation Bar</label>
       <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
  </block>
</default>
```

and you can call it in 1column.phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

Or you can directly call it

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_topmenu')->setTemplate('page/html/topmenu.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Yes working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Write following code in column1.phtml to get top menu :

```
<?php

$header = new Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header();
echo $header->getChildHtml('topMenu');

?>
```